# Background of ActionBar in mono android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am referring example from https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SlidingMenuSharp/tree/master/Sample
.I want to use FragmentChangeActivity from this example in my app. I want to shane background color of actionbar for this activity only,But I want to keep different background colors for actionbar and sliding frame of this activity.

How can I create such a theme for this activity?

Answer (score 0):

Just use: `ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable();`. You cannot change the entire theme for the `Activity` at run-time without reloading the application. However, `SetBackgroudDrawable` for the `ActionBar` should be sufficient if you just want to change the appearance of the `ActionBar`.